# Victim of bettercap mitm web page times out

Tags: man-in-the-middle, bettercap

For school, I am trying to run a mitm attack using bettercap. I can sniff the traffic without problems, but the real problem is that the victim computer browser times out or says "it is impossible to reach this page". All of this while navigating through http pages. Could anyone help please?

I might have missed something while doing this attack because I am quite new to this.

Commands I run are:

```
bettercap -iface wlan0
net.probe on 
set arp.spoof.fullduplex true (my router does not have any kind of protection so this works)
set arp.spoof.targets x.x.x.x
arp.spoof on
net.sniff on
```

Comment: Whenever you play around with manipulating the network, your troubleshooting steps ***must*** include capturing packets to see what's going on. Start capturing packets on the target and see why there is a timeout and where the packets are going.

Comment: could you please be a little bit more clear on how to understand where the timeout occurs? I am new in this field and i have a very little experience...

Comment: As I said, on the target.

Comment: Was there only one router on the network? Maybe yours is fine with the full duplex but another is not. I would have tried without that first to see whether that could be the culprit.